How to serve dynamic file downloading with axum?
I want to serve dynamic files downloading with axum
async fn download(Path(file_path): Path<String>) -> impl IntoResponse { 
    let file_path = format!("web/{}", file_path); // Add "web/" prefix

    let header_val1 = format!("attachment; filename=\"{}\"", file_path);
    let header = [
        (header::CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream"),
        (header::CONTENT_DISPOSITION, header_val1.as_str())
    ];
    let file = File::open(file_path).await.unwrap();
    let stream = ReaderStream::new(file);
    let body = Body::from_stream(stream);
    (header, body)
}

but it report as an error:
54 |         (header::CONTENT_DISPOSITION, header_val1.as_str())
   |                                       ----------- `header_val1` is borrowed here
...
59 |     (header, body)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function


You need to pass ownership of the header value. Try:
async fn download(Path(file_path): Path<String>) -> impl IntoResponse { 
    let file_path = format!("web/{}", file_path); // Add "web/" prefix

    let header_val1 = format!("attachment; filename=\"{}\"", file_path);
    let header = [
        (header::CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream".to_owned()),
        (header::CONTENT_DISPOSITION, header_val1)
    ];
    let file = File::open(file_path).await.unwrap();
    let stream = ReaderStream::new(file);
    let body = Body::from_stream(stream);
    (header, body)
}

